# Как передать кириллицу при инсерте в базу данных

Tags: c++, postgresql

```
void SQLQuery::queryInsert(std::string str)
{
    work W(*conn.get());

    /* Execute SQL query */
    W.exec(str.c_str());
    W.commit();
}
std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "set client_encoding='ISO_8859_5';INSERT INTO foo(name,phone,status) VALUES ('" << "Имя" << "','" << "123123"
        <<"',false);set client_encoding='UTF8';";
    s.get()->queryInsert(oss.str());
```

Когда я пытаюсь отправить кириллицу, у меня срабатывает исключение:
*ОШИБКА:  неверная последовательность байт для кодировки "UTF8": 0xc4 0xe0*

Разве `set client_encoding='ISO_8859_5` не задает кодировку, почему UTF8? Как это исправить?

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что ваши строки из исходника типа `"Имя"` будут именно в кодировке ISO_8859_5?

Comment: Гм, от того, что я вам скажу, что буду писать по-английски, но продолжу писать по-русски — как по-вашему, текст комментария автоматически станет английским? Просто из-за одного объявления? :)

Comment: @Harry Я не очень разбираюсь в плане кодировок, но они же должны будут кодироваться при отправке, если выводить через `OutputDebugString`, тогда кириллица нормально выводится

Comment: @Harry а как тогда привести все к тому, чтобы я мог нормально отправить запрос?

Comment: @Harry или может можно как-то отправить wstring в exec?